# Sharing a Dropbox link directly to the clipboard, without having a browser pop open?

Tags: sharing, dropbox, links

Is there any solution for retrieving a Dropbox share link to a file, that doesn't involve opening a browser?

That puts it directly in the clipboard.

(For sake of clarity, I'm referring to when you right-click a file and select `Dropbox` → `Share Link`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't just get the link in clipboard, which is much safer for you. With Dropbox's version 2.0.5, you can easily share them through the toolbar.

There's a second way of doing it, being a lot better, which is:

Finder > Dropbox > public (move your public file here) > right click > dropbox > Copy public Link

[image: dropbox share button]

[image: right click copy public link]

Answer (score 2):

Since [September 2013](https://blogs.dropbox.com/dropbox/2013/09/save-your-screenshots-in-dropbox/) Dropbox introduced the possibility to automatically copy the public link of a shared screenshot to your clipboard.

On Mac you can use the default shortcuts <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and the link is automaticlycopied to the clipboard.

On Windows you have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> to get the link copied to the clipboard (If you just press <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> Dropbox will only add the Screenshot to the Screenshots folder).

Answer (score -3):

You can as of a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Assuming the way you have in mind differs from the one in the other answer, can you please elaborate?